UIButton that allows clicks to pass through to button below

I create this image for illustration of my issue.
I have a button that on touch hold changes background to pink.
Then a view in-between the two buttons to display a view.
Then another button on top to add an inner shadow.
I cannot get both targets to work at the same time.
Is this even achievable?
I tried using HitTest without success, as it pass the click to the button below but then then first button loses its target.
I am considering maybe using UIViews to achieve the same effect as I am using Layers inside the button's target to achieve the effect that I am after.
I just need two views on top of each other that can receive touches simultaneously. I would prefer a UIButton solution as the hold touch is almost instantaneous whilst a LongPress gesture takes some time to take effect.
I have been on this problem for quite a while now so I decided to ask some help.

Why do you want "yellow" to be a button, instead of another UIView?

@DonMag If possible yes, hence buttons react fast to touch and hold.

OK - it's not really clear why you're using buttons, or exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Is it something like this? https://i.sstatic.net/3Kfa3njl.gif ... on "touch start" the background color changes and the shadow shows... on "touch up" OR if the touch moves outside the view, the background color changes and the shadow hides.

@DonMag that's exactly what I am trying to do

You can (probably) accomplish this easier by using a UIView and handling touches rather than using a UIButton ...
First, let's create a basic "change background on touch" view:
class HighlightView: UIView {
    
    // very light gray
    var normalColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
    
    // light pink
    var hightlightColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = normalColor
    }
    func doHighlight(_ b: Bool) {
        backgroundColor = b ? hightlightColor : normalColor
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        backgroundColor = hightlightColor
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let t = touches.first else { return }
        let pt = t.location(in: self)

        // if touch is inside my bounds
        //  use highlight color
        // else, touch moved outside so
        //  use normal color
        
        if bounds.contains(pt) {
            backgroundColor = hightlightColor
        } else {
            backgroundColor = normalColor
        }
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        backgroundColor = normalColor
    }
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        backgroundColor = normalColor
    }
    
}

with an example view controller:
class TouchHoldVC: UIViewController {
    
    let holdView = HighlightView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        holdView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(holdView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            holdView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            holdView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            holdView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            holdView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
        ])
        
    }
    
}

On init we set the background color to "normal" ...

when we first touch the view - touchesBegan - we set the background color to "highlighted"
if we move the touch outside the view, set it back to "normal"
if we move back into the view, set it to "highlighted"
on touch up (or cancelled), set it back to "normal"

looks like this:


Next we can create an "inner shadow view" class:
class InnerShadowView: UIView {
    
    // "inner" shadow
    private let innerShadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let innerShadowMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        // add sublayer
        self.layer.addSublayer(innerShadowLayer)

        // fillColor doesn't matter - just needs to be opaque
        innerShadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        innerShadowLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd

    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // for the "inner" shadow,
        // rectangle path needs to be larger than
        //  bounds + shadow offset + shadow raidus
        // so the shadow doesn't "bleed" from all sides
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds.insetBy(dx: -40, dy: -40))
        
        // create a path for the "hole" in the layer
        let holePath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        
        // this "cuts a hole" in the path
        path.append(holePath)
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        
        innerShadowLayer.path = path.cgPath
        
        // mask the layer, so we only "see through the hole"
        innerShadowMaskLayer.path = holePath.cgPath
        innerShadowLayer.mask = innerShadowMaskLayer
        
        // adjust properties as desired
        innerShadowLayer.shadowOffset = .zero
        innerShadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        innerShadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
        
        // setting .shadowOpacity to a very small value (such as 0.025)
        //  results in very light shadow
        // set .shadowOpacity to 1.0 to clearly see
        //  what the shadow is doing
        innerShadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.75
        
    }
    
}

Modify HighlightView by adding InnerShadowView as a subview:
class HighlightView: UIView {
    
    var normalColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
    var hightlightColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    
    let shadView = InnerShadowView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        shadView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(shadView)
        
        let g = self
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            shadView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        backgroundColor = normalColor
        shadView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    func doHighlight(_ b: Bool) {
        backgroundColor = b ? hightlightColor : normalColor
        shadView.isHidden = !b
        
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        doHighlight(true)
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let t = touches.first else { return }
        let pt = t.location(in: self)
        if bounds.contains(pt) {
            doHighlight(true)
        } else {
            doHighlight(false)
        }
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        doHighlight(false)
    }
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        doHighlight(false)
    }
        
}

using that same example controller, now:

when we first touch the view - touchesBegan - we set the background color to "highlighted" and we show the shadow view
if we move the touch outside the view, set it back to "normal" and hide the shadow view
if we move back into the view, set it to "highlighted" and show the shadow view
on touch up (or cancelled), set it back to "normal" and hide the shadow view

Looks like this:


Next, a simple "content view" with an image and a label:
class SomeContentView: UIView {

    let label = UILabel()
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(label)
        
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imgView)
        
        let pad: CGFloat = 8.0
        let g = self
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: pad),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.trailingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -pad),
            
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: pad),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: pad),
            //imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -pad),
        ])
        
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "This an image view and a label, in a view we will call \"SomeContentView\""
        
        if let img = UIImage(named: "test300x300") {
            imgView.image = img
        }
    }

}

by itself, it looks like this:

we'll add a function to our HighlightView -- func addContent(_ cView: UIView) -- so we can add that as a subview:
class HighlightView: UIView {
    
    var normalColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
    var hightlightColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    
    let shadView = InnerShadowView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        shadView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(shadView)
        
        let g = self
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            shadView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        backgroundColor = normalColor
        shadView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    func doHighlight(_ b: Bool) {
        backgroundColor = b ? hightlightColor : normalColor
        shadView.isHidden = !b
        
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        doHighlight(true)
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let t = touches.first else { return }
        let pt = t.location(in: self)
        if bounds.contains(pt) {
            doHighlight(true)
        } else {
            doHighlight(false)
        }
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        doHighlight(false)
    }
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        doHighlight(false)
    }
    
    func addContent(_ cView: UIView) {
        
        cView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        insertSubview(cView, at: 0)
        
        let g = self
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            cView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            cView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            cView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
    }
    
}

and a couple changes to our sample controller -- we'll add an instance of SomeContentView and let its constraints set the height:
class TouchHoldVC: UIViewController {
    
    let holdView = HighlightView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        holdView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(holdView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            holdView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            holdView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            holdView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // the content view will set the height of the "touch hold" Highlight view
            //holdView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
        ])
        
        holdView.addContent(SomeContentView())

    }
    
}

and we get this:

